# Automated rewriting of string diagrams in symmetric monoidal categories

Tags: graph-theory, monoidal-categories, symmetric-monoidal-categories, string-diagrams

Many algebraic structures, such as Frobenius algebras, or quasi-triangular Hopf algebras, can be formulated in an arbitrary symmetric monoidal category. They are given by a collection of morphisms, and a collection of axioms, which are equations between two different string diagrams.

There are many theorems which hold for any symmetric monoidal category, such as that the antipode of a quasi-triangular Hopf algebra is involutive. Such theorems are themselves equations between two string diagrams. They can be proven by a sequence of axioms translating the one string diagram into the other. Applying an axiom $A=B$ to a string diagram $X$ means identifying $A$ with a part of $X$, and replacing this part by $B$.

Are there any implementations for algorithms which automatically find such a sequence proving an algebraic statement?

I'm aware that something very similar is known as "double-pushout graph rewriting", for which some implementations exist. However, there is a subtle difference between string diagrams and graphs: Whereas in a string diagram, each morphism has different input and output components (e.g., the multiplication of an algebra has a "left" and a "right" input, and we cannot exchange left and right if the algebra is not commutative), there is no distinction between the different edges adjacent to a vertex in a graph.

Is there any implementation of graph rewriting which allows distinguishing the edges adjacent to a vertex?

Answer (score 1):

Double-pushout graph rewriting is actually the basis of a long line of work on automated rewriting techniques for string diagrams: for a very thorough introduction I recommend [Aleks Kissinger's PhD thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.0202).

TL;DR Both morphisms and objects are represented by nodes of a multigraph, edges between them endcode information about which objects are inputs/outputs of which morphisms, and edge labels are used to carry additional information such as ordering.

An implementation of these techniques is available in [Quantomatic](https://quantomatic.github.io/), currently in the process of being replaced by [PyZX](https://github.com/Quantomatic/pyzx).